# Use CString with sprintf

Tags: c++, printf, cstring

I have some C++ code where I need to use CString with sprintf. In this code I'm creating file names that are CStrings that are defined by sprintf. The code is below.

```
double Number;     
Number = 0.25; 

char buffer [50];

CString sFile;
sFile = sprintf(buffer,"TRJFPICD(%3.3f).txt",Number);

CString SFFile;
SFFile = sprintf(buffer,"TRJFPICV(%3.3f).txt",Number);

CString SFFFile;
SFFFile = sprintf(buffer,"TRJFPICA(%3.3f).txt",Number);
```

The desired file names are `TRJFPICD(0.25).txt, TRJFPICV(0.25).txt`, and `TRJFPICA(0.25).txt`. I have to use CStrings for my code.

The error I get is '`operator =`' is ambiguous.

Comment: `sprintf` returns `int` – why would you expect to assign an `int` to a `CString`? Also, use `_stprintf` instead of `sprintf` to avoid unicode issues, or better yet use `CString::Format` instead of any `sprintf` variant.

Comment: Instead of `sprintf`, you could use the `Format` method on the `CString` itself.

Comment: Use this msdn link to find out the exact way of using sprint to copy data into CString object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`CString::Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (ignore the `CStringT` part - `CString` is derived from `CStringT`). It does what you want and allows you to rewrite your code cleanly:

```
double Number = 0.25; 

CString sFile;
sFile.Format(_T("TRJFPICD(%3.3f).txt"), Number);

CString SFFile;
SFFile.Format(_T("TRJFPICV(%3.3f).txt"),Number);

CString SFFFile;
SFFFile.Format(_T("TRJFPICA(%3.3f).txt"),Number);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm NOT a C++ programer. I'm a structural engineer working on my PhD, and I have to use object oriented C++ programing to work with my advisor. When I graduate I will never do objected oriented MFC programing again.

Comment: @Grady : For being forced to use MFC alone you have my sympathies.

Comment: Hey! It's a Ph.D.! He's supposed to suffer a little!